# Lock screen, but show contents

Tags: lock-screen, mate, screensaver

Is there a way in MATE Desktop to lock the screen while showing contents? For example we have a TV in our office which shows Icinga alerts, some Grafana Dashboards, etc. (rotating tabs in Firefox).

We would like to make this PC a little bit more secure so that we still see the contents, but you have to type a password before you can use the PC. How could I do this? (Basically I'm looking for a "transparent" screen saver.)

Comment: Looks like you want a "kiosk" desktop. They're usually locked down heavily from the get go and may provide a feature to lock input but not output.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I'll look into it. We've used "alock" before which was simple enough, but I thought with a new OS I'd look for something better.

Answer (score 0):

Install xtrlock (it's been around a long long time)

```
sudo apt install xtrlock
```

I just open the browser to the page I want and have a plugin refreshing the page at the interval desired.

Then open a terminal, and type:

```
sleep 5; xtrlock
```

This gives you 5 seconds to select the web browser and bring it into the foreground, hiding the terminal, and then it locks the screen. You have to enter the users password to unlock the screen.

Only down side is that it has a little lock icon where the mouse cursor would be, but I just move that into the corner.